# Hold down a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to execute a method when the button pressed and executes another method when it released. I searched a lot in the Internet and didn't understand how to do it, how can I do that ?

Comment: [Check this](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind actions to specific functions with the following example. `on_press` and `on_release` are functions, you don't have to call them with `()` , they will automatically run.

```
button.bind("<ButtonPress>", on_press)
button.bind("<ButtonRelease>", on_release)
```